# Change query to active record in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I want to change this code into active record query and I am have difficulties doing so.

```
 public function get_user($username, $password) {
    $p = md5($password);
    $q = "SELECT u.userid, u.userfullname, u.useraddress
    FROM user u 
    WHERE u.username = ? AND u.userpassword = ?";

    $r = $this->db->query($q, [$username, $p]);
    $this->db->close();
    return $r->result_object();
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason for needing to use codeigniter's implementation of active record? I have always used prepared statements when working with codeigniter (code is more portable if you wind up switching platforms in the future)

Comment: Since CodeIgniter v3.0.0 "Active Record" has been called "Query Builder". Most because that is a more accurate description of what it does. "Active Record" has a specific architectural pattern in programming but that isn't what CodeIgniter's version did.

Comment: Query Builder (QB) is very handy is some cases. But your very simple query isn't one of them. Understand that the purpose of QB is to create query strings that get executed by a call to `db->query()`. So for simple queries you type a lot more code that executes a really rather large amount of code to accomplish what you do in a few lines above. It is important to learn how to use QB, but it is equally important to know when to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the table alias "u" when you're just dealing with a single table. If you're referring to what CodeIgniter now calls Query Builder, then this is your answer:

```
$r = $this->db->select('userid, userfullname, useraddress')
    ->where('username', $username)
    ->where('userpassword', $p)
    ->get('user');

if( $r->num_rows() > 0 )
    return $r->result();

return FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

```
return $this->db->select('userid, userfullname, useraddress')
->where('username', $username)
->where('userpassword', $p)
->get('user')->row();

// if no entry null will be returned
//row returns user as an object row_array() returns user as an array
```

also instead of md5 look at their encryption library
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html